# How to run ionic project in terminal?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic project.I need to run the project in terminal.ionic serve is the command to run the project after changing the file directory.can u help me in identifying the terminal commands?

Comment: what you want to know exactly??

Comment: I am new to the ionic framework.I want to know the terminal commands to run the ionic project.

Answer (score 5):

you can run project by :

> step 1 : go to cmd

[image]

> step 2 : open the ionic project path

[image]

> step 3: open this path in cmd

[image]

> step 4 : run via

```
 ionic serve
```

or

```
ionic serve --lab
```

hope it helps you as a starter!

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all go through the [ionic website](https://ionicframework.com/) and checkout the documentation.... As you mentioned ionic serve will load your app in web view and for more options you may check with[ionic cli](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) els eyou can directly see those in terminal with the command `ionic --help`